# How to delete helm releases for an accidentally deleted namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We accidentally deleted a namespace before listing and deleting the helm releases specific the namespace. How we delete those orphan helm releases now?

Please help

We tried creating the same namespace but cannot list the helm releases. Seems like the name space and the helm releases interlinked with a different id.

Comment: you are using helm 2 or 3?

Comment: We are using helm3

Answer (score 0):

They're gone.

Helm normally stores its state in Kubernetes Secret objects in some namespace you specify when you install the chart.  When you deleted the namespace, you also deleted those Secrets, so Helm doesn't actually know what might have been installed there.

The good news is that a typical Helm chart only installs Kubernetes resources in that same target namespace.  So, if you deleted the entire namespace, it's likely that you deleted not only Helm's state but also the things that Helm installed.  This isn't guaranteed – there are some cluster-global resources, and it's possible for a chart to specify an alternate `namespace:` – but the most common case is that there won't be stray resources.

Assuming you've committed your charts and values files to source control, you should be able to mostly recover by re-running `helm install` on those charts.  If there is some dangling resource in another namespace, this will report a conflict and you can figure out what that resource actually is.